# Can a view inside a navigation controller (inside a popover) use a flip transition?

Tags: ipad, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, uimodaltransitionstyle

I'm not sure it's possible to do this. I have an iPad popover that hosts a navigation controller. I'd like to do an iPhone-standard flip-to-backside for something in that view, and have the contents of the popover flip horizontally to reveal a backside. I tried a couple different things here, but was unable to get just the internal part of the popover to flip.

Can this be done?

Thanks.